# Colour R plot for binomial variable

Tags: r, plot, colors

I've created a plot with a binomial variable, which has values of 0 and 1. 
In the resulting plot, I want to clearly see which of the circles in the plot belong to the category 0 and which to 1. I am able to give the circles different colours, but not in the way that corresponds with what I just mentioned. Does anybody happen to know how to get this done?

Comment: Hello, welcome to stack overflow. Please, could you provide a sample data? It's easier for people to help you if you show what have you done so far.

Answer (score 1):

In base R, the `plot` function takes an argument `col` that determines the color of the points.  Consider the following:

```
# generate some random data to plot
dataPoints = runif(50)
# plot all points as green points
plot(dataPoints, col = "green", pch = 20)
```

[image: Plot with green points]

Now lets create a random binomial "type" (either 0 or 1) for each point:

```
# generate a random "type" for each point; either 0 or 1
dataType = sample(c(0,1), 50, replace = T)
```

Using the binomial type, we can make a vector of colors, rather than just specify a single color:

```
# create a list of colors for each point, based on "type" of point (0 or 1).  
# 0 = "red" and 1 = "blue".
colorVector = c("red", "blue")[dataType+1]
```

Check out the contents...

```
> dataType
 [1] 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0
> colorVector
 [1] "blue" "blue" "blue" "red"  "red"  "blue" "red"  "red"  "blue" "red"  "red"  "blue" "red"  "red"  "red"  "red" 
[17] "red"  "red"  "red"  "blue" "blue" "red"  "red"  "red"  "blue" "blue" "red"  "blue" "blue" "blue" "red"  "red" 
[33] "red"  "blue" "red"  "red"  "red"  "red"  "red"  "red"  "blue" "blue" "blue" "blue" "red"  "red"  "blue" "blue"
[49] "blue" "red"
```

Now, tell `plot` to use the color vector for colors -- the first point will be the first color in the color vector, the second point will be the second color in the color vector, etc.

```
plot(dataPoints, col = colorVector, pch = 20)
```

[image: Plot with point colors determined by a vector of color names.]

Finally, if the list of colors is shorter than the list of points, the color vector is recycled...

```
plot(1:30, col = c("red", "blue", "green"), pch = 20)
```

[image: Plot with recycled c("red", "blue", "green") vector.]